# R glm regression not including several dummy variables

Tags: r, logistic-regression, dummy-variable

I have a data set (`acs_hh`) in which one of the columns is `race_eth`.

For the following regression:

```
reg <- glm(acs_hh$own ~ acs_hh$hhincome + acs_hh$race_eth, family = "binomial")
summary(q7reg)
```

[image: Results]

However, in my data there exist more than just the four races mentioned in the summary; asian is also a race in my dataset.

Why is R not calculating a coefficient for asians, i.e `acs_hh$race_ethasian`, non-hisp ?

Comment: also, are you sure that "several" are not included, and it's not just "asian"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using dummy variables one of the categories is excluded and serves as the reference category to which all the others are compared. So to calculate fitted values for Asian, non-hisp you would set all of the other categories to 0.

Comment: I am an idiot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because "asian" is the reference level of `acs_hh$race_eth` -- all the other coefficients represent the effect relative to the reference level (which in your case, I suspect is `"asian"` because that is the alphabetically first level).